# Is every path in a space a kind of "line"?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question, fundamental-groups

Recall that a path in a topological space $X$ is a continuous map $[0,1] \rightarrow X$, where $[0,1]$ is the real unit interval.

Now, thinking about paths, and also about the $\pi_1(X,x)$, I can only imagine paths which really looks like some kind of "curved segments", which naively looks like "a segment", perhaps very strange, but segment-like.

There is a topology, for every set $X$, for which there are continuous maps from the unit interval which are not like that naive idea I have of a loop, the trivial topology. The problem is, that in the trivial topology the points of $X$ are not distinguishable, and so I find that this particular example is as trivial as the path $[0,1] \rightarrow \{pt\}$ *(where $pt$ stands for point)*, and so it is not a useful example, for me, in a topological and geometrical sense.

So, I'm asking:

- Are there examples of paths in a space $X$ which are different from what a path looks like in a (say) $CW$-complex? (i.e. a curved, perhaps very strange, segment)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: This is an interesting example, thank you. But it is also true that I can find an homotopy between this path, and another one which is of the naive type as above, using the elementary properties of the $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is contractible. I was searching for topology in which the *nature* of a path is completely different from the one above.

Comment: Alrighty then, how's this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet

Full disclosure: I have no idea how to realize the carpet as a path.

Comment: If a space-filling curve and the trivial topology don't satisfy you, then I'm afraid I really don't understand what you mean by "the nature of a path".

Comment: Actually, now that I think about the Sierpinski carpet, we call it a ``curve" because it has Lebesgue covering dimension 1, but I am not sure if it is necessarily a path.

Answer (score 0):

A path can be very unlike a curved segment for it can cross itself numerous times, even infinitely many times.  An arc, which is a path with an image homeomorphic to [0,1] is exactly like a curved segment.  In a Hausdorff space a path from a to b can be reduced or short cutted to an arc from a to b.